# fread and read.table giving dissimilar outputs according to identical() in R

Tags: r, fread, read.table

I have a text file containing space delimited characters say:

```
a b c d e
```

I am reading this `.txt` file using two different ways and then I compare the two readings as follows:

```
a <- fread("C:/Users/user/Desktop/New Text Document.txt",header=FALSE,data.table=FALSE)
b <- read.table("C:/Users/user/Desktop/New Text Document.txt")

> identical(a,b)
[1] FALSE
```

Why is the outcome of `identical()` for these two readings is dissimilar when I know that both `a` and `b` contain the same data, have the same class, and same `str`? is it a problem with fread or a problem with the `identical` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** use `as.is` to prevent `read.table` from converting strings to factors, or `stringsAsFactors=TRUE` to enable the same behaviour in `fread`.  Use `str` to figure this out.

```
writeLines("a b c d e",con="tmpabc.txt")
str(A <- read.table("tmpabc.txt",header=FALSE))
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ V1: Factor w/ 1 level "a": 1
 $ V2: Factor w/ 1 level "b": 1
 $ V3: Factor w/ 1 level "c": 1
 $ V4: Factor w/ 1 level "d": 1
 $ V5: Factor w/ 1 level "e": 1
str(B <- data.table::fread("tmpabc.txt",header=FALSE,data.table=FALSE))
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ V1: chr "a"
 $ V2: chr "b"
 $ V3: chr "c"
 $ V4: chr "d"
 $ V5: chr "e"

C <- read.table("tmpabc.txt",header=FALSE,as.is=TRUE)
identical(B,C)   ## TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you, I overlooked that part in the documentation since I don't know what factors mean in R context. I will accept your answer as soon as I can.